# How to get server path in spring boot rest api

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2, tomcat8

I have one server on which two tomcat server has been configured. I have deployed a spring boot API war on both tomcat. But both server API writing logs in same file mentioned in the logger configuration file.

*logging.config=//home//user//config//testlog4j2.properties*

I want to separate log file for both server using same war.
Is there any option to get server path like *../tomcat/temp* in application.properties

Comment: You can use environment variables.

Comment: @EugenCovaci, but environment variable can be used after deployment and log4j2 initialized at deploying war

Comment: We find a solution. Define environment variable in tomcat's sentenv file say **LOG_FILE_PATH=/path/to/tomcat/conf** for every instances of tomcat. and set **logging.config=${LOG_FILE_PATH}/testlog4j2.properties** in application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an environment variable.

Let say you define the environment variable `TOMCAT_LOG_DIR=/path/to/tomcat/location/log` for both servers.

In `application.properties` just put:

```
logging.config=${TOMCAT_LOG_DIR}/testlog4j2.properties
```

Now you can deploy it  on both servers.

**Note**

`log4j` is initialized on application startup.

Comment: suppose the server paths are */home/user/tomcat1* and  */home/user/tomcat2* at same IP, then which one will picked up using ${TOMCAT_LOG_DIR}.

Comment: i just want on application startup it dynamically pick respective log4j2 file.

Comment: We have two servers tomcat1 and tomcat2 then it will not be dynamic path